# NumericUpDown removes zero for decimals

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an AJAX NumericUpDown Control that takes a decimal. If I put in 1.30, it removes the zero. I do not want to remove the zero, it must remain at 1.30.

A demo of this can be found here:
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/NumericUpDown/NumericUpDown.aspx

For example, enter 1.30 in the text box then tab out or click somewhere else. The zero is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the Javascript code needs to be modified. If this is an open source component, please explain what part of the code you do not understand, and we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure - try adjusting the "Step" property to 0.01